# What is the difference: Tapas (तपस्) vs Yajna (यज्ञ)?

Tags: scripture, culture, identification-request, sanskrit, terminology

What's the terminology difference between *Tapas*-austerities and *Yajna*-sacrifice/perseverance?

Also when to choose one over the other?

Comment: Tapas is shunning the desires which takes away from the truth. And Yajna is a spiritual practice which takes us closer to the truth. Yajna is positive counterpart of Tapas IMO.